# How to start 3 different java programs concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have 3 java programs in a package each having its own main method (Test1.java, Test2.java, Test3.java). I want to start these 3 programs concurrently from another java program, such that Test1 java should run every 60 seconds, Test2.java should run every 10 mins and Test3.java should be run every 30 mins. How can I achieve this? Any solutions? 
I kow java multithreading will help here, But I am not sure how do i control the timing of these programs as mentioned above.

Comment: Infinite loop in a Thread and letting the Thread [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Comment: Look at the Java concurrency package and ExecutorService.  No one should be creating raw Threads anymore.

Comment: Do you need to launch your programs from Java directly ? You could use a Crontab (on linux) to do this kind of things, no Java programming required. Other than ExecutorService, Quartz is a good java library for job scheduling (although its power comes with a somewhat more complex use than pure ExecutorService).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

> An ExecutorService that can schedule commands to run after a given
>   delay, or to execute periodically.

Following Exampl will help you

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Do your first concurrent work here
    }
};

executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You can do the same for other two tasks!

Comment: If some tasks will need to run every 10 and 30 minutes then single thread may be not enough. You should probably change `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` into something like `newScheduledThreadPool(3);`.

Comment: Thanks Pshemo. Yes you are right. I am using newScheduledThreadPool(3) to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

One of options is `java.util.Timer` which can schedule some tasks.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task1");
    }
}, 0, 1000);

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task2");
    }
}, 0, 2000);

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task3");
    }
}, 0, 3000);
```

At each task you can simply call main method of your other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/):

If you want to run jars directly [check here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-cron-job-to-run-a-jar-file/)
If you want to run methods or classes [check here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

The patterns you need:

```
0 * * * * ?     // run each 60 seconds
0 0/10 0 * * ?  // run each 10 minutes
0 0/30 0 * * ?  // run each 30 minutes
```